# argument 1 missing or nil

Tags: lua, roblox

i am making a tower defense game but it keeps saying argument 1 missing or nil
when i try to spawn the tower
this is a module script
(error at line 11)

```
local PhysicsServive = game:GetService("PhysicsService")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PhysicsService = game:GetService("PhysicsService")
local events = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Events")
local Tower = {}
local SpawnTowerEvent = events:WaitForChild("SpawnTower")


function Tower.Spawn(player, Name, CFrame)
   local towerExists = ReplicatedStorage.Towers:FindFirstChild(Name)
    if towerExists then
    local newTower = towerExists:Clone()
    newTower.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame
    newTower.Parent = workspace.Towers
    newTower.HumanoidRootPart:SetNetworkOwner(nil)
    for i, object in ipairs(newTower:GetDescendants()) do
        if object:IsA("BasePart") then
            PhysicsService:SetPartCollisionGroup(object, "Tower")
            object.Material = Enum.Material.ForceField
        end
    end

 else
    warn("Missing:", Name)
  end
end

SpawnTowerEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(Tower.Spawn())

return Tower
```

Comment: provide working code fragments of where and how you call the spawner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SpawnTowerEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(Tower.Spawn())
```

`Connect` expects a function value, not a function call (unless that function call resolves to a function value). Remove the call operator `()`.

```
SpawnTowerEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(Tower.Spawn)
```

You call `Tower.Spawn` without any arguments. Therefor you call `FindFirstChild(nil)` which causes the observed error.
Also it does not return a function value.

Comment: Thank you so much you are my hero

Comment: reading manuals gives super powers ;-)